# Arranging one field in array

Tags: c++

I have been having trouble trying to arrange the minutes from highest to lowest after the original table has been displayed in the console. The program takes a comma-delimited file and prints it on the console but I need to rearrange it after loading the file.

This is the original table

ID                       Last Name                First Name               Phone Number             Minutes

1 Doe Jane 905-222-2222 888

2 Doe John 905-555-5555 1020

3 Morrison Jim 905-777-777 700

4 Mitchell Joni 416-333-3333 112

5  Barnett Courtney 905-666-6666 455

The minutes should have been displayed like this, just after the original table

ID                       Last Name                First Name               Phone Number             Minutes

1 Doe Jane 905-222-2222 1020

2 Doe John 905-555-5555 888

3 Morrison Jim 905-777-777 700

4 Mitchell Joni 416-333-3333 455

5  Barnett Courtney 905-666-6666 112

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int const NUM_RECORDS = 6;
    int const NUM_FIELDS = 5;


    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("L02_input.csv");


    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        string line = "";
        int foundPos = 0, startPos = 0, y = 0;
        array<string, NUM_FIELDS> record;


        for (int x = 0; x < NUM_RECORDS; x++)
        {

            getline(inputFile, line);

            foundPos = 0, startPos = 0, y = 0;
            while ((foundPos = line.find_first_of(',', startPos)) != -1) {
                record[y] = (line.substr(startPos, foundPos - startPos));
                y++;
                startPos = foundPos + 1;
            }
            record[y] = (line.substr(startPos, foundPos - startPos));
            y++;


            for (int z = 0; z < y; z++)
            {
                cout << record[z];
                if (z < y - 1) {



                    for (int a = 0; a < 25 - record[z].length(); a++)
                        cout << ' ';
                }
            }


            if (x == 0)
            {
                cout << '\n';
                for (int a = 0; a < 110; a++)
                    cout << '-';
            }
            cout << '\n';
            int n = sizeof(record) / sizeof(record[0]);
            sort(record[4], record[4] + n, greater<int>());
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                cout << record[i] << " ";

        }
        inputFile.close();


    }



    cout << "\n\n\n<PRESS ENTER>";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

this is what I tried for the minutes first, but it shows nothing on screen

```
int n = sizeof(record) / sizeof(record[0]);
            sort(record[4], record[4] + n, greater<int>());
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                cout << record[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Perhaps that's because the shown code spews a boatload of compilation errors, and your compiler refuses to even compile it, for many reasons? Why don't you try to fix all the compilation errors, first?

Comment: You skipped describing your actual results.

Comment: You can't use the `sizeof` "trick" with container object (like `records`). But `std::array` like any other standard container have a [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) member function that returns the number of elements. You could also use a [ranged `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead.